# Why can't Renci.SshNet create a hash algorithm from 'SHA512' for a .NET MAUI Android release?

Tags: c#, android, sftp, maui

I have an application in .NET MAUI that connects to a server via sftp and downloads a file. When debugging, everything works as expected. But as soon as I release the app for Android (target V.13, min V.9), I get the following stacktrace when connecting to the server:

```
Could not create HashAlgorithm from `SHA512`. Arg_ParamName_Name, hashAlgorithmName    at Renci.SshNet.Security.Cryptography.RsaDigitalSignature..ctor(RsaKey rsaKey, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithmName)    at Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile.Open(Stream privateKey, String passPhrase)    at Renci.SshNet.PrivateKeyFile..ctor(Stream privateKey, String passPhrase)
```

This is the code I am using to connect to the server:

```
public void Connect()
{
    MemoryStream keyStream = new(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privateKey));

    keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(keyStream, privateKeyPassword);

    PrivateKeyConnectionInfo keyConnectionInfo = new(host, port, username, keyFile);

    client = new SftpClient(keyConnectionInfo);

    client.Connect();
}
```

Comment: Generally, if it works in Debug but not Release, it’s a Linker issue.  See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/linking?tabs=vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jason, it was a linker issue. To solve this, I disabled trimming and aot for the release.

Project Properties -> Android -> Options -> Enable AOT compilation & Enable trimming

Comment: 1. Yes, you can also set the property in ths csproj file like  `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-android|AnyCPU'">
        <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
        <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
      </PropertyGroup>`. 2.  You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.